# discord.py make command cooldowns

Tags: discord.py

How can I make that a command has a cooldown

I have this code:

```
@commands.command
async def reward(self, ctx):
    ctx.user.send("You claimed your reward")
    Money.add(user.id, 50)
```

I want that the command can only used every 5minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work:

```py
@commands.command
@commands.cooldown(1, 300, commands.BucketType.user)
async def reward(self, ctx):
    ctx.user.send("You claimed your reward")
    Money.add(user.id, 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `@commands.cooldown({rate}, {time},commands.BucketType.{type})`.

The `rate` is the number of usages of the commands per basis (like if you put 2 for example, it will become 2 usage commands per basis)

And for the `time`, you can put any time you want, as long it's on seconds, if it's not a second like 5 min, convert the minutes to seconds (5m x 60sec = 500sec).

And lastly the `commands.BucketType.{type}` is the type based either on a per-server, per-channel, per-user, or global basis. there are 4 types of it:

- `BucketType.default` for a global basis.
- `BucketType.user` for a per-user basis.
- `BucketType.server` for a per-server basis.
- `BucketType.channel` for a per-channel basis.

You can find more about it [Here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L907)

And for the updated code :

```py
@commands.command
@commands.cooldown(1, 300, commands.BucketType.user)
async def reward(self, ctx):
    ctx.user.send("You claimed your reward")
    Money.add(user.id, 50)
```